# Как сделать SearchView с выпадающим списком?

Tags: android

Как сделать SearchView с выпадающим списком?

Видел много уроков как используя ListView и SearchView сделать некий фильтр, но это не много не то, так как ListView занимает и перекрывает поле.

В MAterial Design видел такое что после ввода текста, появляется выпадащюий список, так вот как этот список сделать?

Comment: Хоть какие нибудь мысли дайте чтоли

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используй `AutocompleteTextView` , для такой задачи он и создан.

Comment: Но причем тут выпадающий список?. SearchView и так смесь AutocompleteTextView. Просто должна быть штука у него которая включает выпадающий ListVIew

Comment: @xTIGRx вы можете сам AutocompleteTextView вставить куда угодно а list результатов тоже куда угодно, вас в этом не ограничивают, в чем принципиальность использования searchView?